# Debian fails to resume after hibernation

Tags: linux, debian, hibernate

my laptop sometimes fails to resume Debian (output of `uname -v`: `#1 SMP Debian 4.1.3-1 (2015-08-03)`) on resume a lot of *orphaned inodes* are cleaned. I have noticed that this mostly fails when either power was connected when hibernating and not connected when resuming, or the other way around. But, I tried to reproduce this failure and it didn't happen.

> What is going wrong? how can I make my Debian resume without caring if it is connected to power or not?

Comment: I get this consistently with Debian Testing on (older) laptops, since some time in 2016. Did you figure out any reason, per chance?

Comment: hello! well, I am not an expert and the Debian documentation warns hibernation is still experimental... I haven't found a solution for my laptop (not so old - 2011, intel-dualcore...). I now switched my Debian from gnone to lxde, added a swapfile and have a total of 3xRAM-swap-space. (pm-)Hibernation seems to work good but it is too slow! slower than power-off-power-on, so I've stayed with (pm-)suspend by now... also, now I only use one OS and one harddrive... before I had 2, so hibernation (when it worked) was really helpful. may be trying the 3-times-RAM-swap-space-rule could help you?